# How to print with UIPrintInteractionController without the printing options dialog

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I am trying to print photo with wi-fi printer without displaying printing options dialog
I want to press button and and print. How can I disable the "printing options" dialog ?

I am using the following code :

```
UIPrintInteractionController *printController = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
printController.printingItem = imageFromCurrentView;
UIPrintInfo *printInfo = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGrayscale;
printController.printInfo = printInfo;
printController.showsPageRange = YES;
[printController presentAnimated:YES completionHandler:completionHandler];
```

Comment: Why you don't want to show it ? Its a standard way of printing in iPhone. Even if it s allowed and if there are multiple wifi printers, how are you going to handle from which printer you will be printing ?

Comment: i want to print with one button press , and to choose  which pinter and anther options in the code

Comment: Could you find a way to do that?

Comment: @nkongara there can be many reasons, so there's no need to question a question for goodness sake. Our problem is that you can expand the preview area and share your document through iMessage, thing that would breach the security of our app. Did you ever find a way?